# How to pass variables to FXG files in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I made a drawing in Illustrator and exported it as FXG file to be used in my Flex App which is working fine. But now I want to change some settings inside FXG programatically, namely changing color inside the FXG file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a .fxg file you won't be able access anything inside of the file since the compiler optimizes it.  You can almost think of it as an image file that can scale.  Sounds like you might want to be using MXML Graphics, see this post for an explanation of the difference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS145DAB0B-A958-423f-8A01-12B679BA0CC7.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I ended up converting the fxg to MXML in order to pass variables.